# Earphone cable resistance

Tags: resistance, cables

Earphone cables are usually very flexible - does anyone know how much resistance they tend to have? Are they cable of carrying 2A at 5V? My guess is that they are copper strands, but I'm not sure how many strands there are to make them so flexible.

[image]

Could they be used as power cables?

Thanks

Comment: How big is a piece of wood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some googling, earphone/headphone cables has 18-26 AWG gauge.
With the assumption we are using the thinnest cable (AWG 26), from [the AWG gauge specification](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm), the maximum current for chassis wiring is 2.2 A, and for power transmission is 0.361 A.

It has resistance 134 ohm/km or 0.134 Ohm/meter. Using this cable for 2 A, we can expect power dissipation 0.536 W/m and voltage drop 0.268 volt/meter that is very big.

Comment: Oka and Andy are right. It's virtually impossible to answer specifically as there is no standard cable type for headphones. If you are using the cheapest earbuds i would say forget it. But if you are using premium headphones then perhaps. But at that price just get the right wire for the job.

Comment: I double that "get the right wire for the job". Also, I really doubt that even the better quality earphone makers would spend money in a wire capable of carrying 2 amps for this application.

Comment: @ricardomenzer I agree re 2amp. I posted that before I saw the photos of the earbuds. I was thinking of stereophile headphones that often come with pretty decent cables.